# Game Programming: Critical Area protection

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How would you go about protecting a shared resources in cocos2d so that only one class or method is allowed to access or change it at one time? My initial though was to setup a class that handles Lock / Unlock coordination as follows:

```
- (BOOL)requestLock {
    if (self.lockAvailable == YES) {
        self.lockAvailable = NO;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)returnLock:(CGFloat)time {
    self.timer = 0;
    self.timeToUnlock = time;
}

- (void)update:(CGFloat)dt {
    self.timer += dt;
    if (self.timer > self.timeToUnlock) {
        self.lockAvailable = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

But it just doesn't seem to be working as expected. After one of my classes grabs a lock, it calls performs some action, then `returnLock` for however long that action is expected to take.  The results are unexpected, however, as it seems like any other class trying to request a lock can do so no matter the time provided before an unlock. Do I have some sort of flaw here?

On another note: is this going to end up being horribly inefficient at some point? I have about 3 classes trying to access the same resource every update. Every single time they are calling 'requestLock' over and over and over.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed this is an 'update' scheduled by cocos2d, even though you have multiple accessors in the same update cycle, they are never going to access simultaneously - AFAIK cocos2d runs on a single thread.

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else, then, since its all a cocos2d scheduled update. Are UIGestures thread safe? That might be the problem